# How to prevent adding extra double quotes in a string using ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible

The following registry value is having a path which is surrounded by double quotes.

```
win_shell: |
        $((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | `
        where { $_.DisplayName -match '{{product_name}}' }).UninstallString) -split " -"
  register: out
```

The uninstallstring value is as below (with a double quotes)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{584775F9-1696-4387-AEB5-86171F6567CC}\Setup-x64.5.0.1.8009.exe"
```

When i assign the result into set_fact ,it adds one more double quotes to the string.

```
- set_fact: uninstall_filePath="{{out.stdout_lines.0}}"
- debug: var=uninstall_filePath

ok: [Myremotehost] => {
    "uninstall_filePath": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallShield Installation Information\\{584775F9-1696-4387-AEB5-86171F6567CC}\\Setup-x64.5.0.1.8009.exe\""
}
```

Due to this extra double quotes , I am unable to use this path to do uninstallation. how to remove double quotes from string? or how to prevent adding one more extra double quotes to string?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to work with both double AND single quotes. Something like this:

```
"'this is a string'"
```

Just play around with these or alternative try the escape character

```
\
```